# How to call maven from ant without starting a new jvm process?

Tags: java, maven, ant

This is which I would like to change to something didn't calling an unneeded jvm. I want to call mvn from the jvm running ant.

```
<target name="theTarget" depends="clean">
    <exec executable="cmd.exe">
        <arg line="/c mvn.bat release:prepare release:perform -B" />
    </exec>
</target>
```

Practically I am thinking about the inverse of the maven ant plugin. I need some like "ant maven plugin". Does it exist? What is its name?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will probably want [maven ant tasks](http://maven.apache.org/ant-tasks/).